# Launcher not diplaying ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn’t load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Missing menu and launcher can't get any applications as launcher and menu are missing happened after downloading updates